# reloading parent page to the same location using Colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using colorbox and I'm reloading the parent page after closing the 
box.

```
$(".abc123").colorbox({width:"400", height:"90%", iframe:true}, 
function(){ 
$().bind('cbox_closed', function(){window.location.reload();}); 
});
```

My question is: how do I reload and move the browser to the exact same 
location on the page instead of reloading and going to the top of the 
page ? (the user makes the action way bellow the fold, it's annoying 
making him scroll back again...)

Thanks, 
Ilay

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this

```
$("html,body").scrollTop(300); // 300 is just a example
```

with scrolltop you can set the vertical scroll bar at any place you want

you can caculate where you are and set it.

you can use window height and document height property's and calculate where you are..